# Helm template prefixes range index with an underscore

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

We can access the index by this way :

```
{{- range $i, $s := (some list) }}
{{$i}}
{{-end }}

output:
0
1
..etc
```

However when the list is a result of a string split, the index becomes prefixed with an underscore

```
{{- range $i, $s := (split "X" "aaXbbXcc") }}
{{$i}}
{{-end }}

output:
_0
_1
..etc
```

why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `split` function returns a dict, whose index members are prefixed with a `_` character before. It is useful when you are planning to use  dot notation for accessing members and not ideally suited for iteration with `range`.

For accessing the result as a list of strings with their indices, use `splitList`. See [documentation](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/string_slice.html) for more information

```
{{- range $i, $s := (splitList "X" "aaXbbXcc") }}
{{$i}}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: clear, thank you!